# PHP practice function ($result) can't be called

Tags: php

I am doing PHP practice and I am stuck on this part.

My problem is when I do simple math like 1+1 or 1/1 etc. The $result won't display. I am confused about which part of my code is causing the problem.   Please enlighten me on my mistakes

Thank you.

```
       <?php
         $first_num = $_POST['first_num'];
         $second_num = $_POST['second_num'];
         $operator = $_POST['operator'];
         $result = '';

         function cal_result($first_num,$second_num,$operator){
              if (is_numeric($first_num) && is_numeric($second_num)) {
                    switch ($operator) {
                        case "Add":
                        $result = $first_num + $second_num;
                        break;
                        case "Subtract":
                        $result = $first_num - $second_num;
                        break;
                        case "Multiply":
                        $result = $first_num * $second_num;
                        break;
                        case "Divide":
                $result = $first_num / $second_num;
                }
            return $result;        
           }  
         }
      ?>

    <form action="simple_calculator.php" method="post" id="quiz-form">
            <p>
                <input type="number" name="first_num" id="first_num" required="required" value="<?php  cal_result($first_num,$second_num,$operator); ?>" /> <b>First Number</b>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="number" name="second_num" id="second_num" required="required" value="<?php cal_result($first_num,$second_num,$operator); ?>" /> <b>Second Number</b>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input readonly="readonly" name="result" value="<?php  echo $result; ?>"> <b>Result</b>
            </p>
            <input type="submit" name="operator" value="Add" />
            <input type="submit" name="operator" value="Subtract" />
            <input type="submit" name="operator" value="Multiply" />
            <input type="submit" name="operator" value="Divide" />
    </form>
```

Comment: `cal_result` returns a value. But does not echo it. You call `value="<?php cal_result(...); ?>"` (maybe you meant to write `<?= cal_result(...); ?>`/`<?php echo cal_result(...); ?>`), the result is lost because you dont do anything with it. You need to take a look at [variable scopes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) to understand why $result is not accessible outside of your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused by the short open tag

if I print

```php
<?=$result;?>
```

or

```php
<?=cal_result($first_num,$second_num,$operator);?>
```

this is the same thing like

```php
<?php echo $result;?>
```

or

```php
<?php echo cal_result($first_num,$second_num,$operator);?>
```

If you call a function that ´returns´ values, and you want to use them , you must also print them out...

also check out global variables. If you want to use **$result** outside the function scope you must declare it a global variable.

```php
<?php
  $result = '';
  $first_num = 0;
  $second_num = 0;
  
  $ops = array( "+", 
                "-",
                "×",  // HTML : &times; , ASCII CODE : 158 
                "÷"); //  HTML : &divide; , ASCII CODE : 246

  // checking if the first number is what he should be
  if ( isset($_POST['first_num']) && 
      !empty($_POST['first_num']) && 
      is_numeric($_POST['first_num']) )
  {
    $first_num = $_POST['first_num'];
  }

  // checking if the second number is what he should be
  if ( isset($_POST['second_num']) && 
      !empty($_POST['second_num']) && 
      is_numeric($_POST['second_num']) )
  {
    $second_num = $_POST['first_num'];
  }
  
  function cal_result($first_num,$second_num,$operator){
    
    // optionally you can assign global
    global $result;
    
    // here we prevent injection by acceptint only operators from the ops array
    if (isset($_GET['operator']) && in_array($_GET['operator'],$ops)) {
      switch ($_GET['operator']) {
        case $ops[0]: // first element of array ops is Add
          $result = $first_num + $second_num;
          // remember this function is just returning the $result 
          // variable it is not printing it, you will have to assiging 
          // the function to a variable if you want to use the  
          return $result;
        break;
        case $ops[1]: // second element of array ops is Subtract
          $result = $first_num - $second_num;
          return $result;
        break;
        case $ops[2]: // third element of array ops is Multiply
          $result = $first_num * $second_num;
          return $result;
        break;
        case $ops[3]: // fourth element of array ops is Divide
          // divide by zero problem
          if($second_num !== 0){
            $result = $first_num / $second_num;
          }else{
            $result = "Err: Div By Zero";
          }
          return $result;
        break;
      }
    }    
  }
}



?>
<p>
    <!--// now you have 2 possibilities :                 //-->
    <!--// first you can call the global variable $result //-->
    <label for="quiz-form"><?=$result;?></label>

    <!--// the second possibility is to call the function //-->
    <label for="quiz-form"><?=cal_result($first_num,$second_num,$operator);?></label>

    <b>Result</b>
</p>
<!-- for post you should also set enctype for security reasons -->
<form action="simple_calculator.php" 
      method="post" 
      id="quiz-form" 
      enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <p>
            <input  type="number" 
                    name="first_num" 
                    id="first_num" 
                    required="required" 
                    value="<?=$first_num;?>" />
            <b>First Number</b>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input  type="number" 
                    name="second_num" 
                    id="second_num" 
                    required="required" 
                    value="<?=$second_num;?>" />
            <b>Second Number</b>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" name="operator" value="+" alt="Add" />
        <input type="submit" name="operator" value="-" alt="Subtract" />
        <input type="submit" name="operator" value="×" alt="Multiply" />
        <input type="submit" name="operator" value="÷" alt="Divide" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi 

Thank you so much for helping me yes the global variable did the trick. 
I learn something new today thanks again. 

P.S sorry for the late check, I was busy with school.